# New FB Canvas (810px) is cut off

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I am developing an app on facebook.
Since yesterday the resizing worked fine with the following snippets:
CSS:

```
body, html { overflow:hidden; width:810px;margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }
```

Right before the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true,100);
</script>
```

On Facebook I chose fixed for height and width, but that should not matter due to the autoGrow.

Since today it is just cut off, I tried the fluid settings but it did not change anything. I can remove the css rules for body and html, but then scrollbars are added.

So in short:
The resizing does not work anymore at all.

Important to know (maybe) the app resizes dynamically (via JS) without a page reload.

The code did not change at all, so I am worried Facebook might have changed something?

Besides I also tried this js snippet without any effect (but it does the same anyway):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
window.setTimeout(function () {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()
}, 250)
};
(function () {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e)
}());
</script>
```

UPDATE:

The question was answered correctly, but one more thing to notice:
Apply `overflow:hidden` just to the `body`, it worked after I removed `html` from the rule - worked with the old canvas, at least I used it before.

Also putting the code in the header did not change anything as well and is not the same as putting it at the beginning in the body area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId : 'YOUR APP ID', //Your facebook APP here
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        });
      }

      window.onload = function() {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(91);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: I added my app id, but it does not have any effect :-/

Comment: Okay... actually it works sometimes, probably not, if you are expanding the content too early I'll test this now - might be the solution.

Comment: I read in your question "Right before the closing body tag:" try putting the script just after the opening <body> tag. Put <style>
body {overflow:hidden;} </style> between your <head> tags and not in the styelsheet

Comment: Thank you very much... that easy ;-) But I was sure I read everywhere it should be placed before the closing tag :-) I did not have to put the css rule directly into the file - just putting the code at the top was enough (I already tried before putting the js code into the header area, but it did not work as well).